# If $a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 + c ^ 2 - ab - bc - ca = 0$ then find the value of $(a ^ 2)/(b ^ 2) + (b ^ 2)/(c ^ 2) + (c ^ 2)/(a ^ 2) - (a ^ 2)/(bc)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is

$$\frac{a ^ 2}{b ^ 2} + \frac{b ^ 2}{c ^ 2}+\frac{c ^ 2}{a^ 2}-\frac{a ^ 2}{bc} $$
How to solve the above question using simple identities?

Comment: I would recommend you to notice that
\begin{align*}
a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2} - ab - ac - bc = 0 & \Longleftrightarrow 2a^{2} + 2b^{2} + 2c^{2} - 2ab - 2ac - 2bc = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (a - b)^{2} + (a - c)^{2} + (b - c)^{2} = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow a = b = c
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leading on from the comment posted, $a = b = c$ implies that one of the variables can equal all the other variables.
Therefore:

$\frac{a^2}{b^2} + \frac{b^2}{c^2} + \frac{c^2}{a^2} - \frac{a^2}{bc} = \frac{a^2}{a^2} + \frac{b^2}{b^2} + \frac{c^2}{c^2} - \frac{a^2}{a^2} = 1 + 1 + 1 - 1 = 2$

*Note: For $\frac{a^2}{bc}$, making $a$ equal to both $b$ and $c$ gives you $\frac{a^2}{a^2}$, which equals $1$.*

Comment: Thanks, but shouldn't 1+1+1-1=2?

Comment: Thanks! Will correct.